# Need a spinner like this

Tags: android, layout, spinner

I want to add a spinner in my app like the below image.  Actually this drop down spinner should contain contents which can be selectable and also section headers which cannot be clickable.  Some advise to use section in listview, others expandable view.

But nothing helps ..  Please some on help me to complete this.

[image]

Comment: you can do same using [quick action menu](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-apps/quick-action-demo/) or [quickactions](http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/)

Comment: I need a list view with selectable items and also non-selectable items.  thats it...

Answer (score 3):

Check this https://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/ this can be helpful..

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set a Custom dropdown resource to the `Adapter` which is set to the `Spinner` and also you'll need to have a custom `Adapter` which will `setEnabled()` certain items like "View As" and "Sort By" to false.

**EDIT:-** it's `isEnabled()` and not `setEnabled()`.. my bad!

Comment: Can i get sample code for you idea of custom dropdown resource?

Comment: the dropdown resource must contain only a `ListView` and the background should be set with the background color of the image you posted.. and as for the `View` for the section headers, you need a `LinearLayout` with a `TextView` and a `View` with `layout_width` as `match_parent` and `layout_height` as roughly `5dip`..

Comment: @CHAKRAVARTHI.. oops.. my bad.. its `isEnabled()` not `setEnabled()`. You'll be needing to override `isEnabled()` method in your custom adapter class.

Comment: But isEnabled() method never protect the section header to be selected.     this just returns whether it is enabled or not...

Comment: it certainly does.. also override `areAllItemsEnabled()` and make it return `false`